# Best way of modifying code to avoid hibernate4 deprecation warning

Tags: hibernate

After upgrading from hibernatte3 to hibernate4, the old project code throws warning messages:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker [HqlSqlWalker.java:929] [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 56.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
```

The answer can be found from the links:

1. [How to fix a Hibernate query with deprecation warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754211/how-to-fix-a-hibernate-query-with-deprecation-warnings)
2. https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7023

But I am wondering what is the best way to modify the following code to avoid this warning?

```
StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer("from Record where 1=1");
List<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
if (subject!= null && subject.trim().length() > 0) {
    hql.append(" and subjectlike ?");
    params.add("%" + subject.trim() + "%");
}
if (startDate != null) {
    hql.append(" and createTime> ?");
    params.add(startDate);
}
if (endDate != null) {
    hql.append(" and createTime< ?");
    params.add(endDate);
}
Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql);
if (params.length > 0) {
   for (int i = 0, length = params.length; i < length; i++)
        query.setParameter(i, params.get(i));
}
List result = query.list();
```

---

==>update20130401,changing the HQL to JPQL style by adding an order number after every parameter mark '?':

```
//first, fomat HQL to JPQL style
private String fomatHQL(CharSequence queryString) {     
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(queryString);
            int start = 0;
            int order = 0;
            while ((start = buffer.indexOf("?", start + 1)) > 0) {
                buffer.insert(start + 1, order);
                order++;
            }
            return buffer.toString();

    }
// second, create Query
// third, set parameters
protected void setParameterList(Query query, Object[] params) {
        if (params != null && params.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0, length = params.length; i < length; i++)
                query.setParameter(i + "", params[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder("from Record where 1=1");
    Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql);
    if (subject!= null && subject.trim().length() > 0) {
        hql.append(" and subjectlike :subject");
        query.setParameter("subject", "%" + subject.trim() + "%");
    }
    if (startDate != null) {
        hql.append(" and createTime> :startDate");
        query.setParameter("startDate", startDate);
    }
    if (endDate != null) {
        hql.append(" and createTime< :endDate");
        query.setParameter("endDate",endDate);
    }
    List result = query.list();
```

Prefer `StringBuilder` to `StringBuffer` as this last is synchronized and so less performant unless you are in a concurrent context (not the case here)

Comment: Gab,thanks! But there are much code like this and the modification would be a lot of work. Exactly,all of them call a method "List queryByHQL(String hql,List params)" , which creates a Query and set parameters. I have an idea that changing the HQL to JPQL style by adding an order number after every parameter mark '?',so it doesn't need to change to call other setParameter methods. How do you think?

Comment: can you please post queryByHQL method content

Comment: Gab, I have added the main part of the method queryByHQL at the end of the question.